# ng-model not updating with input from textbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This seems like a weird one to me. I have a form for adding vets to a dog walkers' database. I've used `ng-model` on each field in the form.

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-show="nav.page == 'new'" ng-controller="dataController as data">
    <div class="row" ng-show="nav.tab == 'vet'">
            <div class="col-md-2">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">

                <h1>Add a Vet</h1>
                <hr />
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name..." ng-model="data.creator.vet.Name"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="Text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address..." ng-model="data.creator.vet.Address"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number..." ng-model="data.creator.vet.Phone"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="data.newVet()">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Yesterday it was working fine, today it won't update `data.creator.vet` when I input data. For the life of me, I can't see any problems with it.

The js:

```
app.controller('dataController', function($http) {
dataCon = this;
this.creator = {};
this.creator.client = {};
this.creator.vet = {};
this.creator.client.Dogs = [];
this.allData = {};

this.newVet = function(){
    console.log("New Vet Creating....")
    console.log(dataCon.creator)
    vet = JSON.stringify(dataCon.creator.vet);
    console.log(vet);
    $http.get(SERVICE_URL + "?fn=vetCreate&vet=" + vet).then(function(response) {
        dataCon.init();
    });

}
});
```

Comment: try to add $scope.$apply()  OR time interval (Quick Answr :) )

Comment: I made [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UJ0L4Qk4na6YjMFjiqR4) and everything seems to work fine. So, i guess that the wrong code isn't there.

Comment: @mic4ael nah, No noticable change without data.... `creator.vet` still = {}.....

Comment: My guess is you are re-creating the controller somewhere and your model is initilized. Add console.log in your init and check console if you see controller being constructed more than once.

Comment: @ZivWeissman `init()` runs twice when the document loads, after it's loaded (according to the logs) init isn't called until i submit the vet

Comment: So... there's your answer... if init is called on submit, your model will be empty.

Comment: @GabrielHobold now i'm stumped then, because i don't know where else to look :/

Comment: try changing instead of ng-click, put ng-submit on the form

Comment: @ZivWeissman init is called inside .then() of the HTTP request.

Comment: @JamieMcAllister haha, sorry for that. Could you please provide more code of your controller? Is it too big to post it all?

Comment: @GabrielHobold the controller is in this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/0rc2RpE6XU5A9fqBNad3?p=preview

Comment: @JamieMcAllister OMG, I can't see anything wrong. Even in the plunker your code works.

Comment: I think it's HTML related.... i can call dataCon from the console, and when i look at creator, vet is empty, even after i've filled all the textboxes @GabrielHobold

Comment: @GabrielHobold I updated that plunkr with more of the HTML and the model doesn't appear to be updating now

Comment: the plunker not working cause of the first line in app.js -> nav.page = "new";

Comment: for example - this is working - https://plnkr.co/edit/qfOHIsF7h6Gr8SyzcwUO?p=preview

Comment: for some reason it's now working on plunkr.... i copied the changes over and it's not working -_-

Comment: Your current plunker - https://plnkr.co/edit/0rc2RpE6XU5A9fqBNad3?p=preview is working fine...

Comment: okay, so i copied over the code from plunkr and tried it on my site... the model updates on the page, but `console.log(dataCon.creator)` tells me the vet object is empty (the model still has values on the page... thoughts?

Comment: I found the data... I can access it through `$scope.data.creator.vet` but not through `dataCon.creator.vet`.... weird, right?